# Can I integrate android code in java applications?

Tags: java, android, javafx

Android ExpandableListView would be quite interesting to implement in my java application. Yet, javaFX only comes with ListView (as far as I know). Can I use Android imports/source code in my application or do I have to adapt it somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use Android imports/source code in my application

Generally speaking, no. In particular, Android's widget classes, including `ExpandableListView`, are not designed to be used anywhere other than Android itself. While, in principle, you could port `ExpandableListView` to JavaFX, it would be simpler for you to write your own two-level list in JavaFX directly, rather than have to port *everything* needed to get `ExpandableListView` itself to work on JavaFX.